# Android Studio Back Button Problems

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For so far. I have created a simple quiz application on Android Studio. Everything works fine, including when I go from the FirstActivity.java to the Next Activity, which is named SecondActivity.java, and close the first activity with finish(),when the button is pressed, as shown in the following code:

```
 public void onClick () {   

    button_next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextbtn);


            button_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
                    finish();


                }
            });
```

The code works great But when I try to go from the Second Activity to the First Activity (Closing the Second Activity and going back to the first Activity), neither finish() nor onBackPressed() is working, it just closes the application completely, what code do I need to as soon as I press the button, close the SecondActivity.class and go to the FirstActivity.class?

Comment: Don't call finish then

Comment: `finish();` what do you expect this to do?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just using finish(); so the application doesn't consume memory. Because I want my app to have at least 20-30 questions and maintain performance

Comment: I mean, making multiple questions and at the same time leave some RAM memory left on Android. Close SecondActivity and go back to FirstActivity, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to previous activity, dont put finish after you change your activity.

```
public void onClick() {
    button_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbtn);
    button_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is not what I'm talking about, what I'm talking about is to close the FirstActivity and start SecondActivity, that works fine. But what I want is to close the SecondActivity and go back to the FirstActivity

Comment: yes i know, but you put finish in your first activity, so it will destroyed after you move to second activity. If you want to go back from second to first when pressing back button then dont destroy the first activity.

Comment: How am I going to make the app run smoothly if there are too many activities open? I want my app to have at least 20-30 questions

Comment: then i recommend you using [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead of activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have so many activities ,there is another way handle activity life cycle:

```
public class MyActivityManager {
    private static MyActivityManager instance;
    private Stack<Activity> activityStack;//activity's stack
    private MyActivityManager() {
    }
    //singleton
    public static MyActivityManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyActivityManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    //push an activity to stack
    public void pushOneActivity(Activity actvity) {
        if (activityStack == null) {
            activityStack = new Stack<Activity>();
        }
        activityStack.add(actvity);
    }
    //get last activity，fifo
    public Activity getLastActivity() {
        return activityStack.lastElement();
    }
    //remove an activity
    public void popOneActivity(Activity activity) {
        if (activityStack != null && activityStack.size() > 0) {
            if (activity != null) {
                activity.finish();
                activityStack.remove(activity);
                activity = null;
            }
        }
    }
    //finish all activity
    public void finishAllActivity() {
        if (activityStack != null) {
            while (activityStack.size() > 0) {
                Activity activity = getLastActivity();
                if (activity == null) break;
                popOneActivity(activity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

at the FirstActivity,you shall add

`MyActivityManager.getInstance().pushOneActivity(FirstActivity.this);`

at the SecondActivity, you want to go FirstActivity or other activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
MyActivityManager.getInstance().finishAllActivity();
finish();
```